# Probability of a maximum value coming from a given distribution amnong many.

Tags: probability-distributions, sampling

Please don't get too cross if this is not phrased well.

I am doing some work on the following problem....
Take $n$ identically shaped distributions with different means $m_1,m_2...m_n$
Ensure that the if $n_{low}$ has the lowest value of $m$ and $n_{high}$ has the highest value of $m$ that there is an overlap between these two distributions.

Take a random value from each distribution $r_1, r_2 ... r_n$.

Let $p_1,p_2...p_n$ be the probability that the random number from that particular distribution be the maximum of $r_1, r_2 ... r_n$

The overlap condition previously ensures that all values of $p$ are non zero.

So as far as I can determine by montecarlo methods if the distributions are continuous then the relationship between $p$ and $m$ can be well approximated by

$p(x)= \exp(a\cdot m(x)^2+b \cdot m(x)+c)$

My problems are

I don't know what type of problem this is so can't search out papers for it. Blatantly it is statistics of some sort anyone any ideas what I should be looking for.

Is it already well known (see above) and my approximation is an approximation to a known formula? (I have tried to find others but the above is the best fit so far)

Finally is there a proper mathematical proof somewhere for the above?

I've been playing with this for at least 5 years on and off and I'm coming to a wall where my mathematical skills can't see over.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the formula a b and c are constants.

Comment: You might want to look at [mixture models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model), though it's not precisely the same kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks for that, as you point out it isn't the same. The nearest I've come to so far is order statistics.BTW

Comment: Are you aware that these probabilities are given by
$$p_i=\int\frac{f_i(x)}{F_i(x)}\prod_kF_k(x)\,\mathrm dx\;,$$
where the $f_k$ and $F_k$ are the density functions and cumulative distribution functions, respectively? That is, are you looking for this general prescription, or for practical ways to carry out the calculation?

Comment: No I wasn't!!  This looks most helpful. Does this formula have a name or where am I likely to find more about it? I've got my approximation (see above ) for calculation.. Interesting to see if the approximation leads from this in some way or whether it is just happenstance.

Comment: Looking at the above formula it is a rewrite of what I know already (Integrate PDF x times  other CDFs ). Not sure how I get from that to my approximation,.

Comment: For what sort of distributions does your approximation work well? It looks like it might be based on normal distributions -- does it work for others as well?

Comment: Yes it seems to work on triangular, uniform, and beta as well as normal.